# Lazy loading + Apply AOT on angular2 project with systemjs builder bundled projects

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-aot, systemjs-builder

Where can i  find sample Angular 2  project about
apply aot and bundling on Angular2 SystemJs project(with lazy load module)?

i do this by angular-cli.
 but how can i do this with systemjs?

Comment: I am having the same problem too. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey, same issue!  Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

This fellow claims to have had it working with a fork of angular seed.  Looks like a combination of bundle and buildstatic but it's not well explained.

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/2140

I'm still trying to figure it out.